# Why do these images have the same entropy?

Tags: image, matlab, entropy

Why do these two images have the same entropy?

These images are created in MATLAB as follows:

```
N = 50;
Z1 = randi([0 1],N);
Z2 = zeros(N);
Z2(1:2:N,1:2:N) = 1;
Z2(2:2:N,2:2:N) = 1;
subplot(1,2,1)
imshow(Z1,'InitialMagnification',800)
subplot(1,2,2)
imshow(Z2,'InitialMagnification',800);
```

And their "entropy" is computed as:

```
entropy(Z1)
entropy(Z2)
```

which results equal to 1.0000.

It's being said, in the help, that entropy is equal to -sum(p.*log2(p)), where p is the counter returned from imshist.
I find difficult to belive that this pictures has the same "amount of randomness" as we see that one on them is higly ordered while the other is totally random. So what?

Comment: I never used those commands, but `p` being a quantity that is derived from `imhist` sounds to me as if the entropy is determined wrt colors. In this case, it does not matter where the pixels are located. If you are not sure what I mean, take a look at the result of `imhist`.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the `entropy` function computes the **zero-order<sup>1</sup> (empirical) entropy**. This means that pixels are looked at in an isolated manner, without comparing them with surrounding pixels.

Thus the *structure* you see in the second image (the color of a pixel *depends* on surrounding pixels) is not taken into account. Rather, the computation only considers the **proportion** (as returned by `imhist`) of black and white pixels; and that proportion is approximately the same in both images.

You can also see it this way: spatial structure is lost when you compute the (zero-order) entropy, just as the spatial relationship between pixels is lost when you compute the image histogram.

As a side note, the resulting entropy is actually slightly less than 1 in `Z1` with high probability, because zero-order entropy is maximized when the proportion is exactly 1/2. Try with `format long` and you'll see something like:

```
>> format long
>> entropy(Z1)
ans =
   0.999663421925701
>> entropy(Z2)
ans =
     1
```

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> This may also be called *first-order* entropy. Calling it "zero-order" makes sense from the point of view of *Markov chains*, as a zero-order Markov chain produces statistically independent values. On the other hand, the name "first-order" makes sense from the point of view of *statistical distributions* . The first-order distribution of a random process defines the probabilities of the possible values at a given instant/position, without considering the statistical relationship with the values at other instants/positions.</sup>

Comment: Thank You! Yes, those images where just to explain my thoughts. I've been analysing time serires and entropy is considered a complexity measure. It is computed as a the rate of -log of "repetition of certain patterns of length N" on "repetition of certain patterns of length N + 1" in the signal. This doesn't seem even near that (even though it's called entropy), infact entropy should help us to distinguisg random content from highly (or higher) informative content;then, is there a way to take into account the repetion of spatial patterns?

Comment: I only know the general definition for a 1D-process (time series), which is the one you mention. The extension to 2D seems conceptually straightforward, but may be hard to implement. I don't know of any built-in Matlab function that computes even "true" entropy in the 1D case